# PHPExcel How to Define New Customer PAPERSIZE (not fontsize)

Tags: php, phpexcel

i need some help about papersize in PHPEXCEL

im using PHPExcel 1.8

**and i wonder how to do this**

if i redirect to **printBigPaper.php** , it will render excel file with 20inch x 25inch print area (Let's Name it : MY_CUSTOM_BIG_PAPER)

and

if i redirect to **printSmallPaper.php** , it will render excel file with 3inch vs 3inch print area (MY_CUSTOM_SMALL_PAPER)**.

**That is all the list what i need to do.**

If i manually use Excel, i can just simply Define new Paper Size once in a lifetime
and then after i generate the excel file, i open it, and simply choose that paper size.

but i want do it automatically using PHPExcel.

**What i've found out is :**

I looked the code at "Classes/PHPExcel/Worksheet/PageSetup.php"
and i found 66 DEFINED PAPER SIZE by PHPExcel

which i thing most of them has not defined yet in my Excel.

I tried to print using number 37 which is PAPERSIZE_MONARCH_ENVELOPE
and it works eventhough i dont have that paper size in my Excel.

It makes me think, 
if PHPExcel can make 66 CONST PAPER SIZE and my excel understand that, i also can DEFINE new PAPER SIZE. So i make CONST MY_CUSTOM_BIG_PAPER as number 67.

then i tried to setPaperSize(PHPExcel_Worksheet_PageSetup::MY_CUSTOM_BIG_PAPER) and it does not give any errors.

but i dont know where to override the code so that PHPEXCEL can understand that if i choose MY_CUSTOM_BIG_PAPER , it will produce 20inch vs 25inch print area

thanks guys, i really hope you guys can help me with this problems.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in mechanism that allows you to define new paper sizes from within your own code.... if you want to add new paper sizes, then you need to change the relevant sections of PHPExcel code (`PageSetup.php`); but you'll also need to modify the underlying Reader/Writer code to handle custom paper sizes.

Note that many of those 66 different paper sizes that are already defined in PHPExcel will not be defined in your version of MS Excel, because many are locale-specific

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, where exactly should i change the writer code? do you have any suggestions for that?

Comment: I don't have any suggestions, because I've never looked at how custom paper sizes are defined in the files